# How to align tkinter widgets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How do I align my `Radiobutton`s? I can add spaces to `test4` but that solution doesn't seem proper. Here's what it looks like at the moment—as you can see `text111111` has extra chars. I've tried using `padx`.

[image: screenshot of current results]

My code:

```
from tkinter import *

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):

        self.iconnum = IntVar()
        self.master = master
        self.master.title('test')
        self.master.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.master.maxsize(500, 250)
        self.master.minsize(500, 250)

        self.test1 = Radiobutton(master, text="test11111111", variable=self.iconnum,
                                 value=1, )
        self.test2 = Radiobutton(master, text="test2", variable=0, value=2, )
        self.test3 = Radiobutton(master, text="test3", variable=0, value=3, )
        self.test4 = Radiobutton(master, text="test4", variable=0, value=4)
        self.test1.grid(row=2, columnspan=1)
        self.test2.grid(row=2, columnspan=2)
        self.test3.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.test4.grid(row=3, columnspan=1)

        self.Checker = Radiobutton(master, text="test5", indicatoron=0, height=1, width=35,
                                   value=0, command=self.icon_switcher) #var=Selection)
        self.Turbo = Radiobutton(master, text="test6", indicatoron=0, height=1, width=35,
                                 value=1, command=self.icon_switcher) #var#=Selection)

        self.Checker.grid(row=1)
        self.Turbo.grid(row=1, column=1,   )

    def icon_switcher(self):
        print("Hello")

root = Tk()
gui = GUI(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: sorry I typod, align

Comment: what kind of alignment do you want? All to the left? All on the same row? All  on the same column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sticky=W` inside your `.grid` for all your buttons to make them align on the left side. And you can also include `pady = 20` to make it not go all the way to the left.

Comment: Than that goes all the way to the left.... there is no way to fix just that one button?

Comment: No for all you buttons, and also set `pady = 20` that way it wouldn't go all the way to the left

Comment: * `sticky="w"` .Quotations  are important otherwise will throw an error

Answer (score 9):

You should use the `sticky` keyword argument in order to align your widgets better when using grid.

```
import Tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
radio = tk.Radiobutton(window, text="I'm a radio")
radio.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.W+tk.E)

window.mainloop()
```

You can use any combination of the `N, S, W and E` members of the `Tkinter` module. This parameter will make your widgets stick to the sides of the cell you have specified, somewhat like justification in text. If your widget is resizable, such as with `Button`, the widget will also automatically resize to fit the cell if you use all of the `N, S, W and E` members.

Important to note is that this can only do so much as to make the widgets stick to the edges of the cell. Sometimes it is necessary to actually resize the cell or move your widget to another cell.

In your example image, you have `Button`s with a set size that is larger than the default size (the example code you provide is incomplete). This causes the cell, and the whole columns that the cells of these `Button`s are in, to become wider. In this case, you might want to use the `columnspan` keyword argument to divide your column into smaller, resizable, parts, so that your `Radiobutton`s can be aligned still better.

```
import Tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
radio_one = tk.Radiobutton(window, text="I'm a radio")
radio_two = tk.Radiobutton(window, text="I'm another radio")
button = tk.Button(window, text="I am a very long button", width=50)
button.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.W+tk.E)
radio_one.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.N+tk.W)
radio_two.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=tk.N+tk.W)

window.mainloop()
```

If you would like more information on what parameters the `grid` geometry manager can use, I suggest you read [this tutorial](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm), I have found it to be very helpful in the past.

As a sidenote, please note that you use the `variable` keyword argument in the declaration of your `Radiobutton`s incorrectly. You must pass either a `tk.StringVar`, `tk.IntVar` or some other comparable object, as described [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/radiobutton.htm).