# Tkbutton align radio buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

[image]

I am trying to align the radio button, I have tried anchor and sticky but doesn't work..I cannot figure out what is the issue

```
smaliButton = tk.Radiobutton(root,
               text="Smali",
               value=2)
smaliButton.grid(row=2,column=0)

byteDexButton = tk.Radiobutton(root,
               text="Byte Dex Classes",
               value=3)
byteDexButton.grid(row=3,column=0,)
```

Comment: Add `sticky="w"` to `.grid(...)`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43170320/how-to-align-tkinter-widgets Here you go.

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you. It looks like I have to add it to every button